# View QObject's objectName in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Unfortunately `QObject` has nothing like a `QString` `m_objectName` member visible in the debugger as one might expect. Instead, all of the implementation data is hidden behind opaque pointers. Is there any way to view the objectName at runtime from within the Visual Studio debugger?

**Background:**

When debugging a Qt Application, there may be many instances of a particular QObject and it can be difficult to know which one triggered a crash, since that information may not available in the call stack. However in the case where they have all been given unique objectNames, that could in theory allow one to quickly pinpoint the problematic code area.

**More Details:**

- I'm using Qt 5.9.3 and Visual Studio 2019
- I've already installed `qt5.natvis` for Visual Studio (and it doesn't do this for you)
- I'm asking for, at minimum, a working watch-expression which can be pasted into the debugger for any local `QObject` derived variable with an objectName, in order to display its objectName.
- The ideal answer will also include the updated `qt5.natvis` which prominently exposes objectName for any local `QObject` derived variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Debug build (`Qt5Cored.dll`), add a variable watch as follows:

```
((Qt5Cored.dll!QObjectPrivate*)myQtObj->d_ptr.d)->extraData->objectName
```

- change "`myQtObj`" to the local variable name of the relevant `QObject*` (or derived class extending `QObject`) that you wish to inspect

I will leave how to add this to `qt5.natvis` for developer convenience as a future exercise, or another answerer may wish to contribute that information.

Comment: When i add your code to watch it shows `Module "Qt5Core.dll" not found`, I'm trying to view the content of the object `match` from: `QRegularExpressionMatch match` is it possible?

Comment: hi @Katia - possibly you need to check your project settings to see which DLL you are linked with. Also, try double clicking different lines in the call stack. Depending on the stack viewed, your Qt DLL may be unlinked to the current project scope.

Comment: `check your project settings to see which DLL you are linked with` I'm a bit new to qt, i tried searching about but still couldn't figure out, do you mind guiding me on how?

Comment: Well, it just depends on your IDE. each one has a way of getting into your Linker settings. And from there you can find a list of all the DLLs you link with. Beyond that, you'll need to create a separate StackOverflow question. Comments are not for that.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger can't (shouldn't?) call object's member function for display purposes, as it can have side effects.

The solution is to write or find "native visualizer" (`natvis`) for the types you are interested in.

Luckily, Qt people did this: https://wiki.qt.io/IDE_Debug_Helpers.

You may be able to do a better custom job following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019

This may point to the data member name (from `qobject.cpp`)
:

```
QString QObject::objectName() const
{
    Q_D(const QObject);
    return d->extraData ? d->extraData->objectName : QString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have the `qt5.natvis` file installed. From my experience (Qt 5.9.3), it does not allow one to view `objectName`. Therefore I cannot mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @PatrickParker I wonder if you can refer to the `D-Pointer` directly? Like `yourObj.d_ptr->objectName` ?

Comment: I am also wondering this, thus my question. :) Seriously though, I have navigated the entire hierarchy of var contents and could not find anything resembling a QString member. I may dig into the QObject source code to figure out where it's stored if no answerer comes to my rescue.

Comment: @PatrickParker please see my updated answer for the source code

Comment: there is no member `d` inside the QObject class. that is the result of a function call. I do see a d_ptr. And I can write `myObj->d_ptr` but I cannot write `myObj->d_ptr->extraData`. Please see for yourself in a debugger with Qt if you think it is answered. I will only consider an answer that provides a working watch-expression.